# Notation for dot product vs multiplication

Tags: notation

Is there a difference in the dot (position, size, etc) used in the vector dot product vs the one use for multiplication?

For typesetting here we use \cdot for both, i.e. $$2\cdot 3$$ or $$\mathbf u\cdot \mathbf v$$ Would that that be correct or is there an more proper alternative?

For instance, in addition to \cdot ($\cdot$) there is also \bullet ($\bullet$).

Comment: In my experience -- no. I personally use \cdot for both, and I haven't noticed any difference in any textbooks/papers I've read. I suspect most people use \cdot for both, off the top of my head

Comment: A search for [`dot product`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=dot+product) on the [TeX StackExchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com) shows results that could be helpful. FYI, I also use `\cdot` dot- and arithmetical-products (also sometimes `\times` ($\times$) in arithmetical contexts), though I'd prefer a "beefier" dot product symbol without the heft of `\bullet`. (Answers to [this TeX.SE question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/235118) suggest how to make one.) If you're submitting to publishers, then individual journals may have specific guidelines about which symbol is appropriate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that typical multiplication is really a special case of dot product in one dimension. In other words, if $x = (x_k)_{k=1}^n$ and $y = (y_k)_{k=1}^n$ with $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^n$, then
$x \cdot y = \sum_{k=1}^n x_k y_k$, so if we are doing this in 1D, we have $x\cdot y = x_1y_1$.

This will explain why the notation is the same.

Comment: Does this logic also apply to the  cross product? We see the "$\times$" symbol used to represent multiplication along with "$\cdot$", which you have already explained, so does that mean that multiplication using the cross symbol is describing a special case of the cross product in one dimension?

Comment: @Kalcifer yes, but it is more funky: $(a,0,0) \times (0,b,0) = (0,0,ab)$